# Not able to Load MimeConent of certain Emails using EWS API

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

When i Try to get the **Mime Content of an email attachment** using below code

`msgAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
                    MimeContent mc = msgAttachment.Item.MimeContent;`

**I am getting the following exception on second line**

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException occurred
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>     Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
>     StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalGetAttachments(IEnumerable`1 attachments, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAttachment(Attachment attachment, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment.InternalLoad(Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment.Load(IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
>          at Presensoft.JournalEmailVerification.EmailVerification.DownloadFailedAttachments(EmailMessage msg, JournalEmail journalEmail) in D:\Source\ProductionReleases\Release_8.0.7.0\Email Archiving\Presensoft.JournalEmailVerification\EmailVerification.cs:line 621
>     InnerException: System.IO.IOException
>          HResult=-2146232800
>          Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>               at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>               at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>               at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName, Func`2 readAction)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.LoadPropertyValueFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, Boolean clear, PropertySet requestedPropertySet, Boolean onlySummaryPropertiesRequested)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, Boolean clearPropertyBag)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment.TryReadElementFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName, Func`2 readAction)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetAttachmentResponse.ReadElementsFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
>          InnerException:

**What I have observed is this occurs when the particular email attachment is Undeliberable email with below content:**

> > The e-mail system had a problem processing this message. Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: MAIL.saaital.com
>
> Hsfsafda@saaital.com
>
> ## 550 5.6.0 M2MCVT.StorageError; storage error in content conversion

Any hints..pointers?? . Really need help on this as I have been struggling for quite some time to process this particular email attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Exchange Server 2010 SP3 RU2? If not, that might fix the issue. Another poster ran into a similar error and they were also sending an email with an attachment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd7ef80e-f80b-47ed-883b-a34511c6233c/a-storage-transient-failure-has-occurred-during-content-conversion?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy.

The support page related to the fix is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863310.

Comment: Its Exchange 2010 on Windows 2008 R2 . I am trying to process Journal Report that contains undeliverable email with above content. Thanks

Comment: So you don't have any service packs applied?

Comment: I don't have any additional recommendations aside from installing the service packs.